# How to build a real-time editable data table in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have json data in the following format.

```
{ "Employees" : [ { "userId":"rirani", "jobTitleName":"Developer", "firstName":"Romin", "lastName":"Irani", "preferredFullName":"Romin Irani",
"employeeCode":"E1", "region":"CA", "phoneNumber":"408-1234567", "emailAddress":"romin.k.irani@gmail.com" }, { "userId":"nirani", "jobTitleName":"Developer",
"firstName":"Neil", "lastName":"Irani", "preferredFullName":"Neil Irani", "employeeCode":"E2", "region":"CA", "phoneNumber":"408-1111111",
"emailAddress":"neilrirani@gmail.com" }, { "userId":"thanks", "jobTitleName":"Program Directory", "firstName":"Tom", "lastName":"Hanks",
"preferredFullName":"Tom Hanks", "employeeCode":"E3", "region":"CA", "phoneNumber":"408-2222222", "emailAddress":"tomhanks@gmail.com" } ] }
```

So, I am trying to display it in a table. So, How can I make the user to select the fields, so that only those data from these fields are needed to display.

So, If a user select userID,employeeCode, Then I need to display only those values in the table. So, if he needed to select other fields, I should give a provision and data is needed to be changed based on the selection.

```
<table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">First</th>
          <th scope="col">Region</th>
          <th scope="col">Phone</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(customer,index) in filteredCustomers">
          <th scope="row">{{customer.userId}}</th>
          <td>{{customer.firstName}}</td>
          <td>{{customer.region}}</td>
          <td>{{customer.phoneNumber}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

So, how can I change the  fields and correspondingly data values

Comment: i had built a npm package which is a data table that i called [vueye-datatable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vueye-datatable) but it doesn't include this option, your question gives me an idea to implement that in the next version, the idea is to make a sub json array with the desired fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

I hope this is what you are looking for https://github.com/allenshaji/vue-editable-table